# Multiple File Upload Validation Message Problem

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, multiple-file-upload

Cake3.6:

I am validating a form field which allows multiple files to be uploaded:

```
$this->Form->input('listing_images. ', ['type' => 'file', 'multiple' => 'multiple']);
```

I have a custom validation provider which correctly validates the multiple images:

```
$validator ->add('listing_images', 'listing_images', [
      'rule' => [
           'dimensions', [
                'min' => ['w' => 100, 'h' => 100],
                'max' => ['w' => 1600, 'h' => 1600]
           ]
       ],
       'message' => 'Maximum image size is 1600 x 1600 pixels',
       'provider' => 'custom'
]);
```

The problem is that when validation fails the validation error does not appear below the field. If make the file upload single file only and name is 'listing_images' the validation error does appear.

Why does it not work for multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may work partially, the trailing dot syntax that you are using isn't supported (and the trailing space only makes things worse), the form helper will not be able to find the field based on that name.

You can use the `name` option to specify a name with trailing brackets as required for a multiple file upload HTML input, while passing the regular field name that the form helper understands:

```
echo $this->Form->control('listing_images', [
    'type' => 'file',
    'name' => 'listing_images[]',
    'multiple' => 'multiple',
]);
```

Comment: Amazing thnak you. I must have tried every other combination. So that I understand fully,which attribute of the field ties the field to the validation rule, is it the 'id', since by calling the field 'listing_images' and overriding the name I can see the 'id' remains ;listing_images' which is required for validation to fire?

Comment: @AlanA (HTML) Attributes have nothing to do with it, the field name must simply match / point to the entity property name, eg `foo.0.bar` will match / evaluate to `$entity->foo[0]->bar` for value lookups, and `$entity->foo[0]->getError('bar')` for error lookups.